# How to pass parameters to Google Cloud Run Job

Tags: parameters, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have ran this [example](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs-on-schedule#command-line) using this [job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/jobs/build-create-java)

Everything worked well.

Now I am trying to see if there is a way to pass parameters to jobs running on Cloud Run.

I understand I can use the command to create jobs with a `--message-body` argument like this:

```bash
 gcloud scheduler jobs create http JOB_NAME \
  --location REGION \
  --schedule="*/3 * * * *" \
  --uri="https://REGION-run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1/namespaces/PROJECT_ID/jobs/CLOUD_RUN_JOB_NAME:run" \
  --http-method POST \
  --oauth-service-account-email  PROJECT-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  --message-body="This is the body"
```

However while checking the documentation for Cloud Run jobs [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs).

I don't see parameters being mentioned anywhere. The idea is that depending on a JSON that contains the parameters we can run different kind of jobs (it's a same job that changes its operation based on the parameters)

Comment: I have not tested this but I believe you can pass parameters via `message-body`. For example, create a JSON object, convert to a string and then base64 encode for the body. On the receiving side, you would grab the POST message body, base64decode ...

Comment: You can't (and I begged the Cloud Run Job PM to implement something, and, obviously, the other alpha testers had the same issue and something will happen :) ). My current solution is to wrap the current batch job in a web server and, as @JohnHanley said, provide a body, parse it, and invoque your batch with that input.

Comment: Hello Guillaume, how would one go about wrapping the job in a web server?

Comment: I suggest that you create a feature request to pass parameters from Cloud scheduler to Cloud Run Job. Please use this link for your [reference](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere can you post the comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry but what do you mean by “invoque your batch”?, how can I invoke the job with that parsed JSON?, do I need to create a scheduler with that message body?, or does the `job execute` API support a body?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Cloud Run Jobs, you can't provide parameters (entry points, args or env vars). I discussed that point with the Cloud Run Job PM to implement something, and, obviously, the other alpha testers had the same issue and something will happen :).

My current solution is to wrap the current batch job in a web server. Package that webserver in a container and deploy it on Cloud Run. Then, provide the correct body, with your parameters, parse it, and invoke your batch with those inputs

Comment: What if I change my API from GET to POST? Move all query parameters to body, is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to change from get to post? ANd you can let query parameters even if you perform a post request

Comment: What's the point of the jobs then? For example we can't use the Google Video Intelligence API in Cloud Run because of timeouts.

Comment: Things are coming! Stay tuned!!

Comment: Cloud Run Jobs now allow you to set env vars on the job itself, and override env vars within the context of each execution. And it's easy to do via the CLI `--set-env-vars` on the `create` and `execute` subcommand, so easy to script. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Do you know if we can use arguments with the `--` sign? I mean, the prompt `--args --arg1,a,--arg2,b` follows with an error because it sees `--arg1` as the next argument. It doesn't response with an error message when I define all the args as string (""), but then in yaml job configuration, all the arguments are treated as a single argument.

Answer (score 10):

This is now possible using the REST API for Cloud Run Jobs.

- [The REST API](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#api) allows passing in a request body
- [The request body accepts an override defnition](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.jobs/run)
- To make the call, you'll need to [get the token of the current executing identity](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#metadata-server)

A full working repo of how to do this is here: https://github.com/CharlieDigital/gcr-invoke-job-overrides

A more in depth writeup here: https://medium.com/@chrlschn/programmatically-invoke-cloud-run-jobs-with-runtime-overrides-4de96cbd158c

The sample is in C#/.NET, but it's easy enough to translate to any other language.

Here's the log output of the environment variables and entry point args:

[image: Cloud Run Job log showing the custom environment variables and entry point arguments]

Answer (score 7):

[UPDATE] Aug 08 2023, this feature (If I'm reading right) [is now in preview](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#override-job-configuration)

Comment: This feature isn't available in the client libraries yet, but is available in the REST APIs for anyone that needs it: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.jobs/run

Comment: Born too early to explore space, born too late to explore earth, born just in time to use arguments with google cloud jobs

Answer (score 5):

You can pass arguments via the [args](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/jobs/create#--args) flag.

They provide an example in this [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-starting-cloudrun-jobs#5) course.

```bash
gcloud beta run jobs create screenshot \
    --image=$REGION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/containers/screenshot:v1 \
    --args="https://example.com" \
    --args="https://cloud.google.com" \
    --tasks=2 \
    --task-timeout=5m \
    --region=$REGION \
    --set-env-vars=BUCKET_NAME=screenshot-$PROJECT_ID \
    --service-account=screenshot-sa@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

This passes an array of args when creating the job and access the right argument by using the `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX` environment variable.

Comment: I don't think this is what's being asked for. This creates a job with arguments, it doesn't allow those arguments to be varied each time you execute that job.

Comment: I do think it solves the problem. You pass an array of args when creating the job and access the right argument by using the CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX variable.

Comment: Forgive me David, I'd not understood that the task index variable could be specified at runtime. Whilst not fully dynamic, this can meet a number of peoples uses. Downvote->upvote :)

Comment: how to pass the `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX` variable during runtime @DavidSpiess?

Comment: `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX` is available as environment variable @AnandShiva

Answer (score 0):

For those using **.NET libraries**  (`Google.Cloud.Run.V2`) to execute Cloud Run Jobs and want to pass `env` and `args` variables to the jobs you can use *container override*.

```cs
    // Create client
    Google.Cloud.Run.V2.JobsClient jobsClient = Google.Cloud.Run.V2.JobsClient.Create();

    // Initialize request 
    var request = new Google.Cloud.Run.V2.RunJobRequest
    {
        JobName = Google.Cloud.Run.V2.JobName.FromProjectLocationJob("[ProjectID]", "[Location]", "[JobName]"),
        ValidateOnly = false,
        Etag = "",
        Overrides = new Google.Cloud.Run.V2.RunJobRequest.Types.Overrides(),
    };
    
    // HERE STARTS: Create a Container Override
    
    var containerModificado = new Overrides.Types.ContainerOverride();
    
    // Create Enviroment Variables

    var enviros = new Google.Cloud.Run.V2.EnvVar();
    enviros.Name = "SALUDO";
    enviros.Value = "HOLA";

    // Add Env Variables to Container

    containerModificado.Env.Add(enviros);

    // Create and add Args Arguments to container
    
    containerModificado.Args.Add("CHIDO1");
    containerModificado.Args.Add("CHIDO2");
    
    // Finally we add the container to Job Request

    request.Overrides.ContainerOverrides.Add(containerModificado);

    // THEN Make the request
    var response = jobsClient.RunJob(request);

    // Poll until the returned long-running operation is complete
    var completedResponse = response.PollUntilCompleted();
    // Retrieve the operation result
    var result = completedResponse.Result;
```